# Open source alert management tool

Tags: open-source

the tool is required for registering alerts for illegal activity and other activities in the form of tickets. Also, the admin should be able to send an email or warning to the respective user about it, informing them about the error dynamically

workflow
1. suppose there is an illegal activity, then the tool needs to raise a ticket.
2. create an alert about it to the user.
3. provide interactive options to close the alert or keep it as pending. I mean the ability to manage it.
4. require easy installation and own dashboard creation for optimization.
5. require MIN 4 users.
6. Alerts are from server. if any customer is facing prob or doing something illegally then there needs to be an ticket/issue in the software and corresponding mails needs to be sent to employees , informing them about the issue. mail should be sent after ticket generation.

Comment: Should the tool CREATE the alerts? Or only "manage" them? Please add more details, including an example alert and its workflow.

Comment: hey Nicolas, I have added the workflow. please look into it

Comment: So, the tool must be able to *detect* "illegal" activity right? What do you define as illegal? For instance, installing a game on my work phone? Can the tool use agents installed on every employee's device and server?

Comment: illegal in the sense that, if for example data not received in server, severe condition, need an alert for the employe to know and then alert the customer and fix the isuue

Comment: Sorry, even with reading the comments, I still don't get what software you need. Where do the alerts come from (Hardware, Software, Servers, ...)? In which form do the alerts come in (text, json, email, REST, ...)?

Comment: i decided to go with trac for this but i am not sure if that is the right tool.